# reading a file with std::ifstream to compile a OpenGL shader doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, gdb, fstream, ifstream

Here is my little function I'm having trouble with:

```
GLuint LoadShaders()
{
    // open and compile vertex shader
    std::ifstream VSS("glfwtest.vert", std::ifstream::ate);
    int len = VSS.tellg() + 1;
    GLchar* vertexSource = new GLchar[len];
    VSS.clear();
    VSS.seekg(0, VSS.beg);
    for(int i=0; i<len ; i++) { VSS.get(vertexSource[i]); }

    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    VSS.close();

    // open and compile the fragment shader
    std::ifstream FSS("glfwtest.frag", std::ifstream::ate);
    len = FSS.tellg() + 1;
    GLchar* fragmentSource = new GLchar[len];
    FSS.clear();
    FSS.seekg(0, FSS.beg);
    for(int i=0; i<len ; i++) { FSS.get(fragmentSource[i]); }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    FSS.close();

    // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    return shaderProgram;
}
```

I have followed [this](https://open.gl/drawing) guide and I managed to render the white triangle correctly. After that I thought it might be a good exercise to split up the whole thing into functions to reuse them later. So I put my shader source code for both shader in seperate files(instead having them directly in my C++ source), and wrote the function above to read them from their respective files.

Now here's the catch: my vertex shader loads and compiles fine, while my fragment shader does not. But when I put my fragment shader source into the code like this

```
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "void main()"
    "{"
    "    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
    "}";

GLuint LoadShaders()
{

    [...]

    // open and compile the fragment shader
    //std::ifstream FSS("glfwtest.frag", std::ifstream::ate);
    //len = FSS.tellg() + 1;
    //GLchar* fragmentSource = new GLchar[len];
    //FSS.clear();
    //FSS.seekg(0, FSS.beg);
    //for(int i=0; i<len ; i++) { FSS.get(fragmentSource[i]); }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    [...]

    return shaderProgram;
}
```

it works fine and shows a white triangle. So the same code that loads and compiles my vertex shader from "glfwtest.vert" does not work for the fragment shader.

I have never worked with `<fstream>` in C++ before and put it together from the [online documentation example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) I found. I guess the error is somewhere there but I can't find it since I am not a C++ wizard (yet).

**EDIT:**

After the suggestions in the comments I'm still stuck. Here's the gdb output I get:

```
(gdb) break main.cpp:55
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4017dc: file main.cpp, line 55.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/georg/code/redbook/glfwtest/glfwtest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, LoadShaders () at main.cpp:56
56      GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
(gdb) p vertexSource
$1 = (GLchar *) 0x8277e0 "#version 420 core\n\nin vec2 position;\n\nvoid main()\n{\n    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);\n}"
(gdb) p fragmentSource
$2 = (GLchar *) 0x82a300 "#version 150 core\nout vec4 outColor;\nvoid main()\n{\n   outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\n}\377\177"
(gdb) p len
$3 = 92
(gdb)
```

As you can see, the length is correctly stored in `len`, there are 92 chars in the source. Still, somehow there are two extra chars. I checked the source file even with a hex editor, those two chars are definitely not in the file.

Comment: Could it be that you are missing a '\0' at the end of the read strings?

Comment: `GLchar* vertexSource = new GLchar[len];` Did you forget to delete these? Because that's kinda important. It's not your problem, but it's still important.

Comment: @BDL: I missed that, but it seems that 'glCompileShader()' doesn't mind if the string terminator is missing since the vertex shader compiles fine. I added it any way, so thanks for that hint.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks for that hint as always, added some 'delete's and the end of the function.

Alas, it my problem persists. Both strings read fine when debugged with gdb.

Comment: @georgjz: `glCompileShader` _will_ read the string until the terminator byte is found, if you tell it to do so (by specifying a `NULL` pointer for the lenghts). The fact that it happens to work in one case but fails in another proves nothing if one is encountering undefined behavior.

Comment: @derhass: Just finished browsing the documentation, and you are of course right. I added a few lines that will add a terminator to the strings as BDL has suggested before. I think I'm close to a solution, somehow the compiler seems to find a `\177' char` in my shader source, even though I have no idea where that comes from.

Comment: @georgjz: Your current code reads one char more than the file provides. `ifstream::get` will return `EOF` in this case, which will be equal `(int)-1`.

Comment: @derhass: any suggestion how to solve this? When reading the second file "glfwtest.frag" for some reason the code adds one or two random chars(often \377 or \177) to the string, but only when loading the fragment shader source, the vertex shader source works fine. Again, it's my first try reading files, so obviously something is eluding me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Skip ahead for a more recent C++17 solution)**

While this answer doesn't debug your code, you expressed an interest in making your routines more modular. Here's something a little more robust that makes use of `std::stringstream`, and eliminates the explicit dynamic memory management:

```
static std::string read_shader_file (const char *shader_file)
{
    // no feedback is provided for stream errors / exceptions.

    std::ifstream file (shader_file);
    if (!file) return std::string ();

    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    auto size = file.gcount();

    if (size > 0x10000) // 64KiB sanity check for shaders:
        return std::string ();

    file.clear();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << file.rdbuf();
    file.close();

    return sstr.str();
}
```

`std::string` is moveable, so you don't need to worry about the cost of returning by 'value' - though it would be trivial compared to GL shader compilation and linking in any case.

```
GLuint LoadShaders ()
{
    ...

    std::string shader_source = read_shader_file("glfwtest.vert");

    const char *shader_source_ptr = shader_source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, & shader_source_ptr, NULL);
    ...
}
```

---

#### C++17

I was reviewing some of my older answers, and realised that I've updated my own `glShader::load` code that I've based this answer on. Firstly, we now have a *portable* path: `std::filesystem::path`, allowing for UTF-16 (?) filename encodings (e.g. wchar_t strings) on Windows for example.

Secondly, GLSL uses the UTF-8 scheme. Hence, there is no reason for `std::wifstream`. As of C++17, `std::ifstream` accepts `(std::filesystem::path)` or `(...path::value_type *)` for the constructor, or the `open` method. see: [path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path)

By enabling exceptions for the `ifstream`, we can hope to capture a `std::ios_base::failure` exception, which inherits `std::runtime_error` if we just want a diagnostic `what()` message. Otherwise `code()` might provide more information - the specification is silent about how informative the diagnostic information will be...

Anyway, here's an idiomatic way to read a GLSL file to a `std::string` :

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <limits>

#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

static std::string read_shader_file
(
    const std::filesystem::path::value_type *shader_file)
{
    std::ifstream ifs;

    auto ex = ifs.exceptions();
    ex |= std::ios_base::badbit | std::ios_base::failbit;
    ifs.exceptions(ex);

    ifs.open(shader_file);
    ifs.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
    auto size = ifs.gcount();

    if (size > 0x10000) // 64KiB sanity check:
        return false;

    ifs.clear();
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    return std::string {std::istreambuf_iterator<char> {ifs}, {}});
}
```

In the event of an exception, resources are unwound and (presumably) a `std::ios_base::failure` exception is thrown. Otherwise, we have a `std::string` which we can now use the `c_str()` method to pass shader source to OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you, Brett Hale! That worked just fine, I had to tweek it a bit by adding `const char* fragmentSource = fragment_shader_source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);`, else it wouldn't compile. Also thanks to all the other commentors, I feel my code improved a lot today :)

Comment: @georgjz - sorry about that. I skipped a step modifying the original code.

Comment: no problem. Funny thing is, I actually tried a similar solution before trying the one above. I got quite close I can see now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been diagnosed by @derhass in the comments, but since the OP still has a problem actually fixing the code:

You need to make sure that the string is null-terminated before you pass it to `glShaderSource()`. If you don't do that, there will be an undefined character at the end of the string, and pretty much anything can happen:

- It could work, if the character happens to be `'\0'`.
- It could give a syntax error based on an invalid character.
- It could crash, if no null character is found before it runs off the end of accessible memory.

To fix it with minimal changes to your code, use this:

```
std::ifstream VSS("glfwtest.vert", std::ifstream::ate);
int len = VSS.tellg();
GLchar* vertexSource = new GLchar[len + 1];
VSS.clear();
VSS.seekg(0, VSS.beg);
for(int i=0; i<len ; i++) { VSS.get(vertexSource[i]); }
vertexSource[len] = '\0';
```

Same thing for the fragment shader.

Comment: I tried your solution as well, and it works fine. Thank you!